# Stagger :nth-child after initial selection?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I cant seem to get this working. I need to start with the 11th `li` and color ever 7th `li` after that initial 11th selected

HTML:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li> //initial selected
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li>
<li>15</li>
<li>16</li>
<li>17</li>
<li>18</li> //selected
<li>19</li>
<li>20</li>
<li>21</li>
<li>22</li>
<li>23</li>
<li>24</li>
<li>25</li> //selected
```

CSS

```
div:nth-child(11){
   color:#00b2ee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `li:nth-child(7n+11)` because the first element that needs to be selected is the 11th element (this goes in the `b` of the `an + b`) and then from there on every 7th element should also get selected (and so the 7 goes in the `a` part of the `an + b`).

In the snippet, I have also included a demo for `li:nth-of-type(7n+11)`. Both the selectors work the same way for `li` elements because only `li` elements are allowed to be directly present under `ul` and hence there are no chance for other type of child elements to be present.

```css
li:nth-child(7n+11) {
  color: #00b2ee;
}
li:nth-of-type(7n+11) {
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
</ul>
```